# Не создается база данных SQLite

Tags: java, android, sqlite

Банальное создание SQLite базы данных Android

```
public class DatabaseHelper extends SQLiteOpenHelper {

    private Context context;

    public DatabaseHelper(Context context, String name, SQLiteDatabase.CursorFactory factory, int version)
    {
        super(context,name,factory,version);
        this.context = context;
    }

    @Override
    public void onCreate(SQLiteDatabase db) {
        Toast.makeText(context, "onCreate", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
    }

    @Override
    public void onUpgrade(SQLiteDatabase db, int oldVersion, int newVersion) {

    }
}
```

Вызываю в MainActivity по нажатию на кнопку

```
public void onInsert(View view) {
        DatabaseHelper databaseHelper = new DatabaseHelper(this,"mydb.db",null,1);

    }
```

Метод OnCreate даже не вызывается, база данных не создается. Проверял на эмуляторе с Андройд 6.0.0 и на Nexus 5 с Андройд 6.0.1 - результатов 0, никаких ошибок не выводится.

Comment: Версию пробовали менять? База поди уже создана...

Comment: Метод onCreate() выполняется только если база не была ранее создана (БД с таким именем не существует), иначе выполняется метод onUpgrade() и то только при увеличении номера версии БД.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

В `MainActivity` выполните:

```
public void onInsert(View view) {
    DatabaseHelper databaseHelper = new DatabaseHelper(this, "mydb.db", null, 1);
    SQLiteDatabase db = databaseHelper.getWritableDatabase();
}
```

Тогда, если БД не существует, отработает `onCreate`, создаст базу и вернет её для работы, если существует, то просто вернет её без вызова метода.